# Segmentation fault and missing libraries

Tags: 18.04, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to run a proram called Realflow, it's a demo version, and when tried to run it gives me an error when launching ./realflow

> strings: 'usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6': No such file

I search for this error and seems to be common, but cannot fix it, could someone explain me how to make it run? Thanks in advance

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Why did you write "segmentation fault"? Did you actually get a "segmentation fault" error message?

Comment: rootsandculture@rootsandculture-X58A-UD3R:~/Documents/realflow/bin$ ./realflow
strings: 'usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6': No such file
Segmentation fault

Answer (score 1):

It looks like libstdc++ isn't installed. Try installling it by `sudo apt install libstdc++6`

Comment: > libstdc++6 is already the newest version (8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04).